# Dynamic size two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, session, asp-classic, vbscript, multidimensional-array

I'm currently working on a webshop. For that i need to make a two dimensional array to store the items moved to the cart.

Cart:

```
Cart = Session("Cart")
Items = Session("Items")
```

And when an item is moved to the cart:

```
Items = Items + 1

Cart(1,Items) = Items
Cart(2,Items) = rs("id")
Cart(3,Items) = Request("attr")
Cart(4,Items) = rs("name")
Cart(5,Items) = rs("price")
Cart(6,Items) = 1
```

And finally:

```
Session("Cart") = Cart
Session("Items") = Items
```

But i'm having issues with the asp lack of proper support of dynamic sized two-dimensional arrays. Or am i just taking it the wrong way? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it not be simpler to store a `ShoppingSessionID` for the user that's related to a table that stores a list of items in the cart? that way all you have to store is `Session("ShoppingSessionID")`.

Comment: This is my next solution.. I do prefer the one explained, but if there aren't decent support for multi-dimensional arrays ehn i'll go for this one.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to create some objects instead of using arrays.  Or even a [structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288471%28VS.71%29.aspx), if it's got no methods.

Here's an expamle of a struct

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom struct type, representing a rectangular shape
/// </summary>
struct Rectangle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Backing Store for Width
    /// </summary>
    private int m_width;

    /// <summary>
    /// Width of rectangle
    /// </summary>
    public int Width 
    {
        get
        {
            return m_width;
        }
        set
        {
            m_width = value;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Backing store for Height
    /// </summary>
    private int m_height;

    /// <summary>
    /// Height of rectangle
    /// </summary>
    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return m_height;
        }
        set
        {
            m_height = value;
        }
    }
}
```

so now you can:

```
Cart[0] = new Rectangle{Width = 1,Height = 3};
```

or

```
Rectangle myRec = new Rectangle();
myRec.Height = 3;
myRec.Width = 1;
Cart[0] = myRec;
```

Swap the Rectangle example with Item, and you should be on your way.
That way, a single instance of each Cart multiple Items that each have their own set of properties.

Comment: I would look into object. You have any code examples or links? I dont need more than one Cart per session - what makes you think that?

Comment: I added an example of a struct to my answer. http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpObjectOriented.aspx is a nice OO tutorial.

Comment: Well, it's actually structures in C#, they're there for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your problem could be solved with a dynamically sized list of item objects. In that case you would want to create an Item class and then add to the Cart list a new Item object for each new item.